# Ejecutar un ciclo en python y que termine cuando unos de los dos haya ganado

Tags: python

```
def turnos(self):
     col = 3
     col2 = 6
     col3 = 6
     col4 = 10
     fuego = random.randint(col, col2)
     rasguño = random.randint(col3, col4)
     don = 3
     don2 = 6
     don3 = 6
     don = 10
     turnoAzul = 1
     turnoRojo = 2
     vidaBlue = 40
     vidaRed = 40

     while True:
         if self.dragon.get() == "fuego" or "rojo":
             self.message['text'] = "muy bien {a}! has escojido al dragon {b} 
             ahora escoje un ataque..".format(a = self.nombre.get(), b = 
             elif.dragon.get())
         if self.ataque.get() == "fuego":
              if fuego == 3:
                  blue = vidaBlue -3
                  self.message['text'] = "le has bajado 3 vidas ahora tiene 
                  {}...".format(blue)
              elif fuego == 4:
                  blue = vidaBlue -4
                  self.message['text'] = "le has bajado 4 vidas ahora tiene {}...".format(blue)
                elif fuego == 5:
                    blue = vidaBlue -5
                    self.message['text'] = "le has bajado 5 vidas ahora tiene {}...".format(blue)
                elif fuego == 6:
                    blue = vidaBlue -6
                    self.message['text'] = "le has bajado 6 vidas ahora tiene {}...".format(blue)

            if self.ataque.get() == "rasguño":

                if rasguño == 6:
                    blue = vidaBlue -6
                    self.message['text'] = "le has bajado 6 vidas ahora tiene {}...".format(blue)
                elif fuego == 7:
                    blue = vidaBlue -7
                    self.message['text'] = "le has bajado 7 vidas ahora tiene {}...".format(blue)
                elif fuego == 8:
                    blue = vidaBlue -8
                    self.message['text'] = "le has bajado 8 vidas ahora tiene {}...".format(blue)
                elif fuego == 9:
                    blue = vidaBlue -9
                    self.message['text'] = "le has bajado 9 vidas ahora tiene {}...".format(blue)
                elif fuego == 10:
                    blue = vidaBlue -10
                    self.message['text'] = "le has bajado 10 vidas ahora tiene {}...".format(blue)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ya que el bucle se hace infinito por esto:

```
 while True:
```

Basta con darle una condición para que acabe.

```
 while blue > 0: # Es infinito mientras blue sea mayor que 0.
```

Pero para ello debes crear blue fuera del bucle, y alterarlo dentro del bucle. El código quedaría algo así:

```
 vidaBlue = 40
 blue = vidaBlue
 while True:
     if self.dragon.get() == "fuego" or "rojo":
         # etcetera
```

**Bonus**
Para ahorrarte mucho código repetido innecesario, convierte todo esto:

```
elif fuego == 7:
    blue = vidaBlue -7
    self.message['text'] = "le has bajado 7 vidas ahora tiene {}...".format(blue)
elif fuego == 8:
    blue = vidaBlue -8
    self.message['text'] = "le has bajado 8 vidas ahora tiene {}...".format(blue)
elif fuego == 9:
    blue = vidaBlue -9
    self.message['text'] = "le has bajado 9 vidas ahora tiene {}...".format(blue)
elif fuego == 10:
    blue = vidaBlue -10
    self.message['text'] = "le has bajado 10 vidas ahora tiene {}...".format(blue)
```

En simplemente esto:

```
elif 7 <= fuego <= 10: # Si fuego está entre 7 y 10
    blue = vidaBlue - fuego
    self.message['text'] = "le has bajado {0} vidas, ahora tiene {1}...".format(str(fuego), str(blue))
```